# Datetime wrong type in database

Tags: entities

i'm triying to create an custom entity, to store data i'm creating a schema through BaseFieldDefinition (or some near). The problem is that some fiels of type datetime are created in the database with type Varchar(20). The field definition is below:

```
        $fields['created_at'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
        ->setLabel(t('Fecha de creación'))
        ->setDescription(t('Fecha de creación de la empresa en el sistema'))
        ->setSettings([
            'datetime_type' => 'datetime'
        ])
        ->setDefaultValue(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I'm triying set the default value with and without ", thanks in advance.

Comment: I want say that values given on setLabel and setDescription are ignored too.

Comment: Side note: Always only pass English strings to the t-function.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Do you need this as a date string, eg '2019-03-05T17:39:00' or as a numerical, unix timestamp, eg 1551825618?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: Date string pls, how the datetime type of mysql native

Comment: I'll try to answer properly when my kid gives back my real computer :) but datetime fields are always varchar in the database since the native database types aren't portable.  The `->setDefaultValue()` should work if you use an ISO8601 string like in my comment above.

Comment: As you can see there: https://imgur.com/Ns21FIQ The default value, is taken as string instead the current timestamp, by other hand, regardless internally mysql trait datetime types as strings, if the field has not the type "datetime" all the native date functions will not available.

Comment: I need know how define the field as datetime from drupal towards database, you know how make this?

Comment: Drupal itself creates date fields as VARCHAR types. Why? I’m not 100% sure offhand.

Comment: Ohhh, ok, is possible get a workaround solution for this?